# Using tkinter's folder choosing dialog box twice

Tags: python, tkinter

At the start of my code, I let the user choose a file and store its path in a text file. Here is the function for that:

```
def choose_folder():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    global DIR
    DIR = filedialog.askdirectory()
    global settings_file  # Somehow works without this line despite being declared in main
    with open(settings_file, "w") as sf:
        sf.write(DIR)
```

Now, I want to let the user change the folder. In the main loop, the user chooses an option each time. Option 4 is to change the directory. Here is my code to change it:

```
elif user_input == 4:
    open(settings_file, "w").close()  # Clear the settings file 
    choose_folder()
```

The problem is, that for some reason the folder choosing dialog box will not open the second time. I've already checked and the code reaches the choose_folder() function but stops running on `filedialog.askdirectory()` (the screen flickers for a second which means that something happens but doesn't open the dialog box). What causes this to happen and how can I fix it?

EDIT: Here's the code snippet (I have also slightly changed `choose_folder()`):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
#other imports


def prompt_continue() -> bool:
    choice = input("Do you want to continue (y/n)? ")[0].lower()
    while choice != 'y' and choice != 'n':
        choice = input("Invalid Input. ")[0].lower()
    return choice == 'y'


def choose_folder():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    global DIR
    DIR = filedialog.askdirectory()
    while not os.path.isdir(DIR):
        print("Please choose a folder.")
        DIR = filedialog.askdirectory()
    while os.listdir(DIR):
        print("Please choose an empty folder.")
        DIR = filedialog.askdirectory()
    with open(settings_file, "w") as sf:
        sf.write(DIR)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    DIR = ""
    settings_file = os.path.expanduser('~/Documents/flagdir.txt')
    if os.path.isfile(settings_file): # if settings file exists
        if os.stat(settings_file).st_size == 0: # if settings file is empty
            choose_folder()
    else:
        choose_folder()

    with open(settings_file, 'r') as file:
        DIR = file.read()

    user_continue = True
    total = 0
    while user_continue:
        print("Choose option:")
        print("[1] Download n random flags")
        print("[2] Enter 2 countries and download their mashup")
        print("[3] Clear the flags folder")
        print("[4] Change the flags folder path")
        print("[5] Print the flags folder path")
        print("[6] Exit")

        user_input = int(input())
        while user_input < 1 or user_input > 6:
            user_input = int(input("Invalid Input."))
        
        if user_input == 1:  
            # working code

        elif user_input == 2:
            # working code

        elif user_input == 3:
            # working code

        elif user_input == 4:
            open(settings_file, "w").close()
            choose_folder()

        elif user_input == 5:
            # working code

        else:
            break

        user_continue = prompt_continue()

    print("Bye!")
```

Comment: Is your program a mix between typing at the command line and the tkinter GUI? How does the user enter the value in to `user_input`?

Comment: You might find that a `root.destroy()` at the end of the `choose_folder` function resolves this issue.

Comment: Yeah, it's currently a mix between the two. The user input is still text-based. The file choosing is the first thing I added which isn't, and I plan to make everything GUI later.

Comment: Also, `root.destroy()` doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate your issue. Perhaps you can share a small but functionally complete snippet of code that exhibits this issue.

Comment: I added the code snippet to the original answer.

Comment: you have to use command `pass` instead of `# working code` to create working code.

Comment: code works without problems on my Linux Mint.

Comment: do you get error message when you run it? What system do you use ?

Comment: @GuyBar With your updated snippet, I am also able to get the dialog to appear multiple times (Windows 10)

Comment: I use Python 3.8 on Windows 10. Really weird... Also, the `# working code` lines are just to indicate that my code there is working and irrelevant to this question.

Comment: I have moved the `root.withdraw()` line to the end of the function and it worked, but now my problem is that I have that small tk window.